# Is there any difference between "captured" and killed XCom operatives?

Tags: xcom-2

Two of my soldiers were labeled as "captured" after I failed to extract them in time, during a "forced retreat" timer mission. They also don't appear in my memorial, so I still have some hope for them! Is captured the same as dead in game terms, or is there a way to recover captured soldiers somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A captured soldier has a chance to appear as a VIP (or mission reward) in a mission and then can be rescued and reinstated.

Comment: I can confirm this. I was eventually given an opportunity to rescue Jane Kelly after an officer parked himself on the top of the only drainpipe to get to the LZ on time. It's a "rescue VIP" flavored mission (so you can either start with them, or have to rescue them), and your captured soldier can't use weapons or abilities.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Good to know.

Comment: That's interesting if true, but effectively not great considering if you had zero captured soldiers you would be getting a free scientist/engineer/soldier anyway. So almost the same as them dying.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I can confirm that I had a case where a grenadier I had to leave behind on the Avenger defense mission (tragically! She was going make it but panicked on the turn I had to pull out) appeared as a VIP to rescue. I didn't put it altogether that this was my lost soldier until after, when she appeared in my roster as "Shaken" but not available. So, it is really cool you can rescue them but as someone else mentioned, they don't help you out afterwards, as far as I can tell.